# Bash - how to split an array element into a list

Tags: arrays, bash

I have a file with a lot of filenames which are formatted like this:

```
filename1;filename2
filename3;filename4
filename5;filename6
```

I've managed to read this into an array for now, so I have 1 line per array element.
But I need to split every element into two elements, with the semicolon as a delimiter. So I would get something like an array in an array, where the inner one has always 2 elements?
As an endresult I'm trying to rename a bunch of files with this array.

How can I split this array, so I get this array within an array?

Comment: Bash doesn't support multidimensional arrays

Comment: You can abuse an associative array.

Comment: Do you have to _store_ the content of the file in memory? Just use the file - read field by field and "rename a bunch of files with this" _file_ (not "with this array"). Are you asking XY question?

Comment: How would that work @KamilCuk? I'm pretty much a beginner...

Comment: Sure - happy reading! https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 You are interested in the `while IFS=: read ....` part - in your case, `IFS=';'`

Comment: Something like `IFS=';' read field1 field2 <<<"${array[index]}"` to set `field1` and `field2` to the first and second parts of the `$index`th line.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to get this to work this way.

Answer (score 4):

#### Split an array element into a list

`IFS=\; read -ra list <<< "${yourArray[0]}"` creates a list/array from your first array entry. **But you cannot use that list as intended**. Bash supports only 1D arrays. You cannot nest arrays.

### Two arrays

Since your number of columns is constant and just 2, you could create one array for each column. This works well if you access `col1` and `col2` in a static manner only.

```
mapfile -t a yourFile
col1=("${a[@]/;*/}")
col2=("${a[@]/*;/}")
```

### Fake a 2D array using an associative array

If you need dynamic access (e.g. the column is chosen by a variable) you *could* use `eval` or reference variables (`declare -n`), but the following hack could be better for small arrays and scrips where you access the array at a lot of different places dynamically:

```
mapfile -t a yourFile
declare -A field
for i in "${!a[@]}"; do
  field["$i,1"]=${a[i]/;*/}
  field["$i,2"]=${a[i]/*;/}
done
```

That way you can access the field in row `$r` and column `$c` using `${field[$r,$c]}`.

For files with more than two columns use

```
mapfile -t a yourFile
declare -A field
for r in "${!a[@]}"; do
  IFS=\; read -ra b <<< "${a[r]}"
  for c in "${!cols[@]}"; do
    field["$r,$c"]=${b[c]}
  done
done
```